# Can Microsoft Studio Create a 3D simulation environment

Tags: visual-studio

I am wondering if Microsoft Visual Studio is capable of creating a 3D simulation environment with a 3D image which can be controlled by real-time interface controller by reading input ON and OFF data from the USB port. Can the Microsoft Visual Studio do all of this by itself, or does it need to have other software packages to act as a simulation platform with Microsoft Visual Studio carrying out the programming part

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. No, Visual Studio itself cannot do 3D graphics from some arbitrary input device. You certainly can code something that will using Visual Studio. That isn't a flaw in VS exactly, but the fact it's an IDE, not a 3D simulator.

Beyond that, it really depends on what you're trying to do and how you plan on going about it. It's likely you'll need some libraries, for the graphics and parsing input, but you need to figure out how exactly those will be handled and what systems, APIs, hardware and software you want to involve.

For 3D, it's likely you'll use Direct3D, and potentially DirectInput or XInput for your input device, although that may need its own library.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Sorry for the confusing question.
Did you mean that Microsoft Visual Studio has to work with other 3D simulator such as OpenGL to create a 3D environment, and the Microsoft Visual Studio does the coding part while the 3D simulator doing the 3D simulation. 
Is there a way that Microsoft Visual Studio can read input data from the USB port?

Comment: VS performs no 3D work itself, so you will need an external library. Direct3D and OpenGL are the two big choices there, depending on what platform and features you need (on Windows, D3D is slightly faster and more maintained, but only provided on MS systems). As far as reading data from USB, that can probably be done through the Windows API, but I certainly don't know how.